# How to subtract two dates in Oracle and extract the year part from the difference?

Tags: oracle10g

My typical requirement is that I want to subtract two Dates cast as timestamp. The Minuend (First parameter) is the current date and the Subtrahend(second parameter) is stored separately as DD, MM and YYYY in three columns. The final output should be a discrete year as number. I am playing with something like :

```
SELECT (TO_DATE('05-DEC-2013') -
    CASE LENGTH(CAND_DOB_DD) 
           WHEN 1 THEN 
           CAST(TO_DATE('0'||CAND_DOB_DD||'-'||CAND_DOB_MM||'-    '||CAND_DOB_YYYY,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') 
           AS TIMESTAMP) 
           ELSE 
           CAST(TO_DATE(CAND_DOB_DD||'-'||CAND_DOB_MM||'-'||CAND_DOB_YYYY,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') 
           AS TIMESTAMP) / 365 END YEAR
    FROM CANDIDATE
```

The Year part as Integer will be used for a very sensitive calculation. Please suggest if the above piece of SCRIPT will yield the desired result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear how this produces a year... or what you're after. Are you looking for the number of complete years between the dates? The year of the date once the second date has been removed (somewhere around 0 I assume?).

Comment: Is the period between 28th Feb 2015 and 28th Feb 2016 exactly equal to one year by your standards, or do you have to wait until 29th Feb 2016 for one year to have past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most purposes you could just use the Months_Between() function to determine the number of months between two dates, and then divide by 12 etc.. Note that the number of months is an integer when comparing two dates that have the same day of the month *or* are both the last day of the month.

This is tricky when it comes to leap years.

Do you count 28th Feb 2015 to 28th Feb 2016 as exactly one year, when 28th Feb 2015 to 29th Feb 2016 is one day longer but plainly is a year?

What about 29th Feb 2016 to 28th Feb 2017, or 28th Feb 2016 to 28th Feb 2017?

Think carefully about these boundary cases, but Months_Between() is likely to be your best choice.

Comment: Ok. But if no one minds, will it be better to pass the date parts to php's DateTime facility and get the years. Actually, my objective is to get flawless output?

Comment: So finally select trunc(months_between('1-apr-2014','1-jan-2013')/12) from dual is the answer? @David Aldridge

Comment: If you want flawless, you first have to define the possible flaws. Then you can ensure that your solution is not susceptible to them.